# Log or Notify every time a redirect happens/particular url is used on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, logging

I have an old link in the format of `/view/id` that I've redirected to `view/category/id`.

I'd like to log or be notified every time this redirect happens, to see if I can catch some leftover code where the old link is used.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can add a custom [ActiveSupport::Subscriber](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Subscriber.html) as below

```rb
# app/subscribers/specify_redirected_subscriber
class SpecifyRedirectedSubscriber < ActiveSupport::Subscriber
  attach_to :action_controller

  SPECIFY_REDIRECTED = [/your-domain\/view\/category\/\d/] # view/category/id

  def redirect_to(event)
    redirected_link = event.payload[:location]
    
    matched = SPECIFY_REDIRECTED.filter { |specify_link| 
     specify_link.match(redirected_link) 
    }
    
    unless matched.blank?
      # log what you want
      Rails.logger.info { "Specify Redirected To #{redirected_link}" }
    end
  end
end
```

then you can add this subscriber at the bottom of application

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # ...
end
SpecifyRedirectedSubscriber
```